# jquery autocomplete() is not working

Tags: jquery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<body>
Search: <input id="example" /> 
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
$("#example").autocomplete(data);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you including the autocomplete plugin? It's not part of jquery core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your example is straight from the [Autocomplete plugin page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete), I'm guessing that's the plugin your attempting to use. You'll need to download it and put it someplace where your code can use it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<!-- You'll want to change this next line to your local copy of the plugin. -->
<script src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script> 

Search: <input id="example" /> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
$("#example").autocomplete(data);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I do what you said and run the script in IE 8 and get error message after typing in the input field:

//error message from IE8 Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.2) Timestamp: Mon, 7 Jun 2010 23:13:10 UTC

Message: Object expected Line: 570 Char: 394 Code: 0 URI: http://localhost/zhong/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js

Comment: I actually used the autocomplete(array) from jquery/plugins. But what I intended to use is autocomplete(source) from jquery/ui. The two autocomplete() have the same name, yet different parameters and different reference. That's why i made the mistake.