# jQuery.autocomplete gives TypeError in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, autocomplete

So I have the following code:

```
jQuery('#id').live('keyup.autocomplete', function () {
    jQuery(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            jQuery.getJSON("link?callback=?", {
                format: 'jsonp',
                ...
            }, response);
        },
        minLength: 2,
        selectFirst: true,
        select: function (event, ui) {
                ...
        }
    })
});
```

In Firefox when I try to use the input it give me:

```
TypeError: jQuery(this).autocomplete is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

select: function( event, ui ) {
```

This error is only in Firefox, on all other browsers it works all fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using and which version of jQuery-ui ? Also take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984659/jquery-autocomplete-is-not-working

Answer (score 4):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

$(*selector*).live(*events*, *data*, *handler*); // jQuery 1.3+

$(document).delegate(*selector*, *events*, *data*, *handler*); // jQuery 1.4.3+

$(document).on(*events*, *selector*, *data*, *handler*); // jQuery 1.7+

Please refer to the link below
http://api.jquery.com/live/